# numpy Polynomial returning errors

Tags: numpy

Following this [basic tutorial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.classes.html#), I tried the following code to create a polynomial.

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P
p = P([1,2,3])
p
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

System info:

```
np.__version__
1.21.5

sys.version
3.8.10
```

I also tried this:

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P
import numpy as np

p = P(np.array[1,2,3])
p
```

And I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `np.array[1,2,3]` is wrong.  `np.array` is a function.

Comment: Are you sure you used the `P([1,2,3])` right after the import?  What does `print(P)` show?

Comment: `P(np.array([1,2,3]))` should work as well as the list case - provided `P` is the imported object.

Comment: Restarted kernel, and original tutorial code works now. Thanks